# How to select rows with timestamp close to adjacent rows?

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2008

I have a SQL table with timestamps as one field. How can I select "adjacent" rows, *i.e.*, rows that have timestamps within a certain delta (*e.g.* 5 seconds)?

Edit:

Sample Table:

```
CurrTime                Weight Length
----------------------- ------ -------------
2017-05-05 12:59:52.000 392    18.18
2017-05-05 12:59:29.000 396    18.18
2017-05-05 12:59:22.000 511    18.5
2017-05-05 12:58:53.000 512    18.5
2017-05-05 12:58:49.000 537    18.5
```

So the query should return:

```
CurrTime                Weight Length
----------------------- ------ -------------
2017-05-05 12:58:53.000 512    18.5
2017-05-05 12:58:49.000 537    18.5
```

Comment: Need a little more information here...  please share some sample data, and desired results.  And share anything you've tried so far.

Comment: @Siyual example added

Comment: Just for one date? One row? Something else?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

using `exists()`:

```
select *
from t
where exists (
  select 1
  from t i
  where i.currtime<>t.currtime 
    and abs(datediff(second,i.currtime,t.currtime))<=5
    )
```

rextester demo: http://rextester.com/LYDBV65396

returns:

```
+-------------------------+--------+--------+
|        CurrTime         | Weight | Length |
+-------------------------+--------+--------+
| 2017-05-05 12:58:53.000 |    512 | 18.50  |
| 2017-05-05 12:58:49.000 |    537 | 18.50  |
+-------------------------+--------+--------+
```

Comment: perfect use case for exists. +1

Answer (score 3):

Something like this... which could be done with cross apply as well.

```
declare @table table (CurrTime datetime2)
insert into @table
values
('2017-05-05 12:59:52.000'),
('2017-05-05 12:59:29.000'),
('2017-05-05 12:59:22.000'),
('2017-05-05 12:58:53.000'),
('2017-05-05 12:58:49.000')

;with cte as(
select distinct
    t.CurrTime
    ,DATEDIFF(SECOND,t.CurrTime,t2.CurrTime) d
from 
    @table t
inner join
    @table t2 on
    t2.CurrTime <> t.CurrTime)

select * 
from cte 
where d <= 5 and d >= -5
```

For cross apply, just remove the self reference by d <> 0

```
;with cte as(
select distinct
    t.CurrTime
    ,DATEDIFF(SECOND,t.CurrTime,t2.CurrTime) d
from 
    @table t
    cross apply @table t2)

select * from cte 
where d <= 5 and d >= -5 and d <> 0
```

Answer (score 0):

As far as I understand, you have an input datetime, and you want to find the rows within `@delta` value. You could use the below if that's the case:

```
DECLARE @datetime   DATETIME    = GETDATE() -- use your valid input date here.
DECLARE @delta      INT         = 5 -- delta in seconds

SELECT *
FROM    YourTable 
WHERE   CurrTime BETWEEN DATEADD(SECOND, -1 * @delta, @datetime) AND DATEADD(SECOND, @delta, @datetime)
```